# Lua - getOrientation() throw Attempt to call global (a nil value)

Tags: ios, lua, autotouch

I am trying to create an autotouch script that will tap 2 different points based on the screen orientation.

This is my script:

```
CREATE_TIME=2017-12-11-19-34-51;
SCREEN_SIZE="0x0";

touchDown(0, 182, 1329);
usleep(16000);
touchUp(0);

usleep(40000000);

local o = getOrientation();
alert(string.format("Screen orientation is : %d", 0))

-- Check for the close button's location
local o = getOrientation();

if o == 1 then
touchDown(0, 1016, 68);
usleep(16000);
touchUp(0);
log("Portrait");

else 
touchDown(0, 1000, 1818);
usleep(16000);
touchUp(0);
log("Landscape");

end;

usleep(40000000);
touchDown(0, 827, 1114);
usleep(16000);
touchUp(0);

usleep(1000);
```

The problem is that on the line with getOrientation i get an error in the log file: attempt to call global 'getOrientation' (a nil value)

Can someone help me with an advice?

Comment: BTW, you probably mean `CREATE_TIME="2017-12-11-19-34-51"`.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you can call usleep and touchDown without invoking an error indicates that getOrientation is not supported by the AutoTouch version you're using.

The only two things I found on that function was the respective entry in the AutoTouch reference, which contains a wrong code example:

```
 local o = getOrientation();
 alert(string.format("Screen orientation is : %d", 0));
```

where `0` should be `o` to make any sense.

Otherwise you will always print `Screen orientation is :0`

and a guy complaining about getOrientation() always returning 1 no matter what he does.

Plus while having a quick look at the Autotouch website I found at least 3 dead links. The last post on their website is from August 2016.

So maybe you're better off using something else. This project doesn't look very promissing to me.

Comment: Yeah, you right about the 0. It's a mistake on their documentation and i didn't see that problem. But anyway the error is on getOrientation() function.

Comment: Do you have any similar application recommendation?